# how to import dart:ui in VSC by using terminal

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, terminal, dart-pub

when i was run my program with debugging in vscode this type of bug in my debug console any solution?

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Canvas, Paint, Path, lerpDouble;
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:ui' is imported through these packages:

    package:practice_1 => package:flutter => dart:ui

/C:/Users/Hp/Downloads/flutter_windows_3.16.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/Users/Hp/Downloads/flutter_windows_3.16.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^

Exited (254).
```